# Why does effect() and predict() produce different model predictions?

Tags: r, predict, mixed-models

Data for this post is available [here](https://universityofadelaide.box.com/s/gp7u3r95a9neur8d1wkdbsv8bry4x5gn) and R script and data available [here](https://universityofadelaide.box.com/s/9rvggk4u7mwoxxhr4xx2mw3p57uoc18w) (R script is also in post below). Thanks in advance for any help.

I have built a series of mixed models in `glmmTMB`. My best two models are below.

```
igm_20 <- glmmTMB(igm_pres ~  fRHDV2_arrive_cat + fseason + sage + save_ajust_abun + fseason*fRHDV2_arrive_cat + (1 | fsite), data = edit_pp_dat, family = binomial)

igm_21 <- glmmTMB(igm_pres ~  fRHDV2_arrive_cat + fseason + sage + save_ajust_abun + fseason*fRHDV2_arrive_cat + sage*fRHDV2_arrive_cat + (1 | fsite), data = edit_pp_dat, family = binomial)
```

I am particularly interested in the interaction `fseason*fRHDV2_arrive_cat`, and so after building my models I created `effect()` plots showing the influence of this interaction on my outcome variable in both models.

```
ef_1 <- effect(term = "fRHDV2_arrive_cat*fseason", mod = igm_20)
windows();plot(ef_1, xlab = "Season", ylab = "Predicted probability of IgM antibody presence", main = "", factor.names = FALSE)

ef_2 <- effect(term = "fRHDV2_arrive_cat*fseason", mod = igm_21)
windows();plot(ef_2, xlab = "Season", ylab = "Predicted probability of IgM antibody presence", main = "", factor.names = FALSE)
```

[Effect plot 1](https://universityofadelaide.box.com/s/ry0rel75e5p5mc53tm51l4uiapmd2eb1)
[Effect plot 2](https://universityofadelaide.box.com/s/6aecr6dfwwjdyrkmor3o69h9oj3omoda)
(Sorry for providing links to plots, i don't have enough reputation to post actual plots)

As seen in the effect plots, the influence of the interaction `fseason*fRHDV2_arrive_cat` is very similar in both models, this is not surprising. I then averaged these two models as follows:

```
mod_ave_list_1 <- list(igm_20, igm_21)
mod_ave_1 <- model.avg(mod_ave_list_1, rank = AICc)
summary(mod_ave_1)
```

From the model averaged results I tried to create a similar `effect()` plot to those above. However, as the `effect()` function does not work with averaged models and the `re.form = NA` capacity in `predict()` to produce population averaged model predictions is not implemented for `glmmTMB` models, I first had to re-create and re-average my two model in another package as follows:

```
predict_1 <- glmer(igm_pres ~  fRHDV2_arrive_cat + fseason + sage + save_ajust_abun + fseason*fRHDV2_arrive_cat + (1 | fsite), data = edit_pp_dat, family = binomial)

predict_2 <- glmer(igm_pres ~  fRHDV2_arrive_cat + fseason + sage + save_ajust_abun + fseason*fRHDV2_arrive_cat + sage*fRHDV2_arrive_cat + (1 | fsite), data = edit_pp_dat, family = binomial)

predict_list_1 <- list(predict_1, predict_2)
ave_predict <- model.avg(predict_list_1, rank = AICc)
```

I then created a `newdata` frame from which I made and plotted model predictions as a means of producing a similar `effect()` plot to that above. I used the mean value for numeric predictors when making model predictions as this is what [another post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9otTx.png) suggests happens when making a call to `effect()`. I included `re.form = NA` in the `predict()` function so that I got population averaged predictions as my models include random effects.

```
a <- as.data.frame(c("Summer", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring"))
a$fRHDV2_arrive_cat <- c("Pre-RHDV2 arrival", "Pre-RHDV2 arrival", "Pre-RHDV2 arrival", "Pre-RHDV2 arrival", "Post-RHDV2 arrival", "Post-RHDV2 arrival", "Post-RHDV2 arrival", "Post-RHDV2 arrival")
mean(edit_pp_dat$sage, na.rm = TRUE) #4.659477e-17
mean(edit_pp_dat$save_ajust_abun, na.rm = TRUE) #-3.004684e-17
a$sage <- c(4.659477e-17, 4.659477e-17, 4.659477e-17, 4.659477e-17, 4.659477e-17, 4.659477e-17, 4.659477e-17, 4.659477e-17)
a$save_ajust_abun <- c(-3.004684e-17, -3.004684e-17, -3.004684e-17, -3.004684e-17, -3.004684e-17, -3.004684e-17, -3.004684e-17, -3.004684e-17)
a$fsite <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
colnames(a) <- c("fseason", "fRHDV2_arrive_cat", "sage", "save_ajust_abun", "fsite")

predict.values <- predict(ave_predict, backtransform = TRUE, newdata = a, se.fit = TRUE, re.form = NA)

a$estimates <- predict.values$fit
a$se <- predict.values$se.fit
a$lci <- a$estimates - 1.96*a$se
a$uci <- a$estimates + 1.96*a$se
a$fseason <- factor(a$fseason, levels = c("Summer", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring"))
a$fRHDV2_arrive_cat <- factor(a$fRHDV2_arrive_cat, levels = c("Pre-RHDV2 arrival", "Post-RHDV2 arrival"))

ggplot(a, aes(x = fseason, y = estimates, colour = fRHDV2_arrive_cat, group = fRHDV2_arrive_cat)) + geom_line(size = 1) + geom_point(size = 3) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lci, ymax = uci), width = .2) + labs(x = "Season", y = "Predicted probability of IgM seropositivity", colour = "RHDV2 arrival category") + scale_color_manual(labels = c("Pre-arrival", "Post-arrival"), values = c("red", "blue")) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16), axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14), legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), legend.text = element_text(size = 12))
```

[Model averaged prediction plot](https://universityofadelaide.box.com/s/wwui1xn3r0l8b20yqiw7pk19si8m0a25)

Why is this last plot so different to the two `effect()` plots produced above? I was expecting them to be very similar. For example, in the two `effect()` plots the predicted probability of igm antibody presence is much lower in summer and winter post-arrival of RHDV2, however in the last plot produced from `predict()`, using the averaged model, the predicted probability of igm antibody presence is higher in summer post-arrival of RHDV2 and similar in winter for both pre-arrival and post-arrival of RHDV2.

I note that there is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897789/effect-vs-predict-function), but that this has not helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be interested, I worked out how to fix my problem. `edit_pp_dat$sage` and `edit_pp_dat$save_ajust_abun` are standardised variables, accordingly their mean is 0. Therefore, `a$sage` and `a$save_ajust_abun` should have been as follows:

```
a$sage <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
a$save_ajust_abun <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I additionally had difficulties on my computer as `edit_pp_dat$sage` and `edit_pp_dat$save_ajust_abun` was a matrix, it appears that `predict()` operates differently according to if the data supplied to the models was in a matrix or dataframe.

I am unsure why `mean(edit_pp_dat$sage, na.rm = TRUE)` and `mean(edit_pp_dat$save_ajust_abun, na.rm = TRUE)` do not give 0.